# How to deal with the multiple threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, message-queue

I am testing threading in local server and client by using python. I've looked at many examples, but they did it in quite different ways. I'am new so it is hard for me to understand it. My code problem is that when client sends only one message, it works fine; however, when client sends multiple messages (using for-loop) or multiple clients send messages at same time, the server receive all the message at same time so it prints in wrong way. Here's part of my code:

for server part:

```
def insert_projects(project):
    ...

class ThreadNum(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            msg = self.queue.get()
            print("Got message", end=' ')
            insert_projects(msg)
            time.sleep(1)
            self.queue.task_done()
def main():
    server_address = (server_ip, server_port)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(server_address)
    print('socket binded to %s port %s' % server_address)
    sock.listen(5)
    print('socket is listening')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    for i in range(100):
        t = ThreadNum(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(buf_size)
        data = ast.literal_eval(data.decode('utf-8'))
        print('received ', data)
        str_message = str(data)
        queue.put(str_message)
        queue.join()
```

The function insert_projects is just to insert message information to mysql database, so it doesn't affect this part.

for client part:

```
# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = (server_ip, server_port)
print('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.connect(server_address)

try:
# Input data
for i in range(3):
    message = {"Project":"KF#2","Type":"GW1","Qty":"12345678","DATE":"18/05/24","TIME":"14:16:20"}
    # Send data
    print('sending ', message)
    sock.sendall(str(message).encode('utf-8'))

finally:
    print('closing socket')
    sock.close()
```

Can someone help me how to divide the received messages one by one into queue?

Comment: If you are using multiple threads things will not run in order anymore. Use one thread to process the queue to keep the order. And BTW `ast.literal_eval` is no replacement for `json.loads`.

Comment: Problem solved. I created two threads to run each connection and use message queue in the threads so that they can process the queue at the same time. And both data receive and insert would be inside queue.